# Почему выдает ошибку “undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass” при запуске тестов RSpec/Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Установил Sorcery для авторизации. Тесты использую RSpec/Capybara/FactoryGirl. До установки Sorcery и системы авторизации тесты проходили нормально.

Файл `card.rb` factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :card do
    original_text "das"
    translated_text "the"
    association :user, factory: :assoc_user
    review_date { Time.now }

    before(:create) do |card|
      card.review_date { 3.days.from_now }
    end
  end

  factory :assoc_user, class: "User" do |f|
    f.email "test1@mail.ru"
    f.crypted_password "$2a$10$Y7wUSADeOiZd94mIiOB4LOgNEljImLOY/YwQeUy275i6uIVkL9K8i"
  end
end
```

Файл `users.rb factory`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email "test@mail.ru"
    crypted_password "$2a$10$Y7wUSADeOiZd94mIiOB4LOgNEljImLOY/YwQeUy275i6uIVkL9K8i"
  end
end
```

Файл `home_controller_spec.rb`:

```
require "rails_helper"
describe HomeController do
  before (:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @card = FactoryGirl.create(:card)
  end

  it "incorrect translation shows proper page" do
    visit root_path
    fill_in "home_cards_review_text", with: "das is fantastish"
    click_button "Проверить"
    expect(@card.check_translation("das ist fantastish")).to be false
    expect(page).to have_content "Перевод неверен"
  end

  it "correct translation shows proper page" do
    visit root_path
    fill_in "home_cards_review_text", with: "das"
    click_button "Проверить"
    expect(@card.check_translation("das")).to be true
    expect(page).to have_content "Список карточек"
  end

  it "opens new card page after click on link" do
    visit new_card_path
    expect(page).to have_content "Новая карточка"
  end
end
```

И `home_controller.rb`:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :require_login, only: [:index, :check_translation]

  def index
    @card = Card.created_before(Time.now).random_record
  end

  def check_translation
    @card = Card.find(params[:home][:cards][:id])
    if @card.check_translation(params[:home][:cards][:review_text])
      @card.set_new_review_date
      render "correct_translation"
    else
      render "error_translation"
    end  
  end
end
```

Тесты выдают ошибку:

```
Failure/Error: visit root_path
ActionView::Template::Error:
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

при попытке отобразить вьюху index.html.erb. Вот он:

```
<h4>Random card for translate</h4>

  <%= simple_form_for :home, url: { action: "check_translation" } do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :cards do |card| %>
      <%= card.hidden_field :id, value: @card.id %>
      <%= card.hidden_field :original_text, value: @card.original_text %>
      <label>Текст</label>
      <p><%= @card.translated_text %></p>
      <label>Transalted text:</label>
      <%= card.text_field :review_text %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Check!" %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Похоже, карточка фабрикой создаётся уже после вызова `@card = Card.created_before(Time.now).random_record`. Попробуйте заменить на `Thing.order("RANDOM()").first` и напишите, что получилось.

Comment: `Thing.order("RANDOM()").first` - какая то незнакомая мне конструкция (((. ВЫдает ошибку `Failure/Error: visit root_path
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant HomeController::Thing`

Comment: Конечно же, вместо `Thing` — название вашего класса: `Card.order("RANDOM()").first`

Comment: Ага, прошли! А в чем разница между моей конструкцией получения рандомной записи и твоей?

Comment: Я думаю, всё дело в том, что ваше решение полагается на то, что Time.now вернёт время ПОСЛЕ создания карточки. А в тестах при автоматизации, похоже, выходит иначе. Посмотрите в дебагере, если интересно.

Comment: Есть ли какая то возможность запустить scope-конструкцию перед созданием карточки? Мне нужно отталкиваться от текущего времени, что бы найти ее в БД `scope :created_before, -> (data) { where("review_date <= ?", data) }`

Comment: А review_date как заполняется?

Comment: `def set_review_date
    self.review_date = 3.days.from_now
  end`

Comment: Все, разобрался! У меня создается карта уже +3 дня к текущему, а пытаюсь выбрать из БД карту с текущей датой, естественно, запрос выдает нулевую выборку. Спасибо за помощь!!!!!